# Get session cookies from facebook with login and password

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible? I'm creating an script the gets my user login and password and try to login in facebook and get the cookies session. I tried with curl, but could just get this cookie:

```
   #HttpOnly_.facebook.com  TRUE
```

With HttpOnly, I need the cookie like:

```
  .facebook
```

is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: you're trying to get the session cookies, but why?

Comment: You are not supposed to do that – scraping their page’s is against Facebook’s ToS, and that includes automated logins; and they are actively taking a number of measures against it. If you want to interact with FB users or content on Facebook – __use their API.__